# How to extract entity wise color, transparency, linewidth of AutoCAD dxf file using ezdxf python package?

Tags: python, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

I'm using ezdxf package in python to read the AutoCAD .dxf file. Can anyone tell me how to extract Line width, Transparency, and Color information of each entity present in modelspace?

I tried the below code:

```
doc = ezdxf.readfile('test.dxf') \
model_space = doc.modelspace() \
if entity in model_space:\
    print(entity.dxf.color)
```

The output will be either 0, 256, or 257 which is indicating, (0-BYBLOCK
256-BYLAYER
257-BYOBJECT)

I need to get the information about each entity. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# iterate over all entities in modelspace
for e in doc.modelspace():
    print(f"layer: {e.dxf.layer}\n")
    print(f"ACI: {e.dxf.color}\n")
    ...
```

See also: [Tutorial for getting data from DXF files](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tutorials/getting_data.html):